# how to get Tibco Spotfire Automation Service job builder

Tags: c#, tibco, spotfire

I am new to Tibco Spotfire. Working on [this](http://stn.spotfire.com/stn/Tutorials/HowToCreateAutomationServicesTask.aspx) tutorial. But I unable to find menu with Tools --> Automation Service Job Builder.  I also installed Automation Services 3.1 on my machine and Spotfire 3.1. What should I install additionally to get it work?

Instead I get this [image]

Comment: The document says you need to have Spotfire Professional Edition. Are you using an evaluation version which might not have this feature.

Comment: Yes I have Spotfire Professional Edition 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deploy it on the Spotfire Server you are connecting to. Please refer to section 1.5 in the [TIBCO Spotfire Automation Services 5.0 Installation and Deployment Manual](https://docs.tibco.com/pub//spotfire-automation-services/5.0.0-nov-2012/TIB_AutomationServices_5.0.0_InstallationManual.pdf).

After deploying the package you need to make sure that the user has the right licenses as well (this is described in the same section).